# What is the "functional programming way" of mapping considering `i, i+1`pairs?

Tags: functional-programming, purely-functional

Consider the following function that takes a vector `[x_1,...,x_n]` and returns a list of `[Line(x_1,x_2), Line(x_2,x_3)...]` in Julia:

```
p(x) = map(Line, x[1:end-1], x[2:end])
```

What is the "functional programming" approach for this kind of operation where we want to use pairs, triples, or multiple values in a loop? In other words, what is the FP method for a "rolling window"?

I thought of using a `foldl`, but this does not work properly, as it returns something like `Line(1,Line (2, Line(3,4)))`. Similarly, the `zip` function does not seem to provide the correct behavior. The functiion should work for any `Vector` type, hence, it should not use stuff like `[2:end]`, where one assumes that the vector has at least two values...

I imagine that `p(x)` should be something similar to a fold in the sense of having an `init`. For a singleton vector could perhaps return `Line(init, x[1])`, and for an empty vector it could return `Line(init,init)`.

Comment: `zip xs (tail xs)` ?

Comment: Does this generalizes to triples and so on? I'm not very proficient on Haskell...

Comment: `fold` is a very flexible function. In most languages `map` is implemented using a `fold`. I suspect there is something wrong with your implementation (the function you are passing to fold). It might be easier to open a `julia` question asking specifically what is wrong with the code